How to prevent premature header filtering and aplly all filters at once
This is a duplicate of the question Tabulator - Is there a way to prevent header filtering and only apply header filters programmatically? I use Tabulator with ajax data fetching. Header filters apply for each column immediately after switching to another column. I want to do one ajax request only after filling all filters (by pushing some button in the header menu or something else).
The custom dataFiltering function or customHeaderFilter did not work for me. Are there any working examples for this case?
